# Is there a way to exclude the content from the post variable to save on RAM usage?

Tags: query-posts, memory

So, I've run into what looks like a WP RAM usage problem and am looking for a solution.

The only place I'm really having this problem on my site is with a Site Map page that I'm trying to populate, but a solution to this problem could be universally applied and save on RAM usage across an entire site.

Essentially, this Site Map page I have is a list of all `posts` and `pages` on my site.  The only elements of the $post variable that I need access to on this page are the title and permalink.  Unfortunately, the query I'm using returns all posts with all the information in each of their $post variables.

The following is an example of a query I'm using on this Site Map page for a single `custom-post-type` named "products" with a custom taxonomy of "supplements" and term "all-supplements".  My Site Map page has multiple such queries, but for explanatory purposes I'm only including the code for this single query.

```
 $varArray= array(
      'post_type' => 'products',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'supplements' => 'all-supplements',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC'
 );
 $myProducts= new WP_Query($varArray);
```

The large majority of the information saved within the $post variable (for my site, and I'm guessing that this trend is seen for general usage) is found within "the content"  The typical RAM usage for my Site Map page is ~140MB (reported by Debug Bar), whereas the usage for any other typical page on my site is 50-60MB.  Big difference.  Yesterday the Site Map page stopped working (WSOD), and to fix it I had to increase the maximum amount of RAM that WP can use.  So I'm increasing overall necessary system resources because of a single page.

Thus, I come to my question.

Is there a pathway/option somewhere within Wordpress that I'm missing that would fetch `posts`/`pages` like a normal query, but *NOT* get the content for retrieved posts?

Or, alternatively, is there some easier way for me to only grab particular elements within a given query (Title/Permaklink/Slug/etc...) instead of getting the whole $post variable shebang?

It seems to me that for many WP applications, the only place that "the content" of a post/page would typically be needed is on that `page` or `post` page (obviously there are exceptions here), and that having access to the full content for posts/pages retrieved by query on other pages is simple overkill.  If there is a way of avoiding loading up the full content for post list pages, then a significant amount of RAM usage could be saved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try a trick with querying post data directly and setting `filter` field of post objects to `sample` before passing it to `get_permalink()` to reduce memory usage.

See [get_permalink memory usage issue](http://yoast.com/get_permalink-memory-usage-issues/) for detailed reasoning behind it.

Comment: This solution worked great.  Well, after a little wrangling that is.  :)  I had to figure out how to include my custom taxonomy/term to the query, but this was a huge help.  Site Map page now using 70MB of RAM (according to Debug Bar).  Thanks for the great pointer.

Answer (score 4):

You might try adding this to your array:

```
'nopaging' => true,
'no_found_rows' => true,
'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
'update_post_term_cache' => false
```

It seems pretty self-explanatory, but essentially you're not querying all post variables and just the stuff you need.

Answer (score 2):

Programmer Dan, mah man!

Let's get you started on custom `SELECT` queries using the `$wpdb` global. The Codex has a great entry on [Displaying Posts using a Custom Select Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query). If you make use of [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) you can loop through the results as though you are sitting in the standard Wordpress loop:

```
global $wpdb;

$sitemap_query = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_title, $wpdb->posts.guid
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type IN ('post','supplement','another_post_type')
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_type, $wpdb->posts.post_title DESC
    ";

$sitemap_nodes = $wpdb->get_results($sitemap_query, OBJECT);

if( $sitemap_nodes ):
    global $post;
    foreach ( $sitemap_nodes as $post ):
        setup_postdata( $post );
        ?>

<!-- //Use standard Wordpress template tags for SELECT'd data within The Loop here -->
    <?php the_title() ?>
    <?php the_permalink() ?>

        <?php
    endforeach;
endif;
```

This query only pulls the posts' IDs, Titles, and GUIDs (used to determine a post's permalink) while absolutely ignoring everything else. It furthermore orders the results first by `post_type` then `post_title`, though you may wish to use multiple queries to separate your post types (theoretically at a small performance hit).

Obviously you may wish to skip out on using `setup_postdata()` and simply loop through `$sitemap_nodes`, or fiddle with the query to get the results that you need.

If you do call `setup_postdata()` and have debug mode activated, the calls will likely be spitting out notices left and right regarding (the deliberately) missing information. You may wish to throw an `@` before the function call to suppress them after you have confirmed that your custom query is functioning properly.

But this should get you started! You can refer to the following database diagram (from the [Database Description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) page on the Codex) to locate the fields that you need to query:

[image: Wordpress Database Diagram]

> **EDIT:**
>
> The most memory efficient solution is likely one that combines a custom `SELECT` query with @Rarst's protip :)

Answer (score 1):

WP_Query has a "return fields" paramater that looks like this:

```
$args = array(
 'fields' => 'ids'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

When used this way, WP_Query only returns the post IDs, not the entire post object. Then you can just use the `get_permalink()`, `get_the_title()`, and other assorted WordPress functions to retrieve your content based on the post ID.

Comment: Note that functions that accept post's ID usually just immediately run `get_post()` on it to retrieve full data and so completely defeat the purpose of retrieving IDs alone.

Comment: Good to know! I was under the impression I was being smart.